# get latest records from mysql result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have my mysql query, which i use in php script:

```
select distinct dhcp_logs_public.service,
dhcp_logs_public.ip,
dhcp_logs_public.date as date,
dhcp_logs_public.until as until
from dhcp_logs_public
where dhcp_logs_public.ip in('79.109.1.200','71.109.160.123','21.110.151.110')
AND dhcp_logs_public.date >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -48 Hour)
```

which gives me this kind of result:

```
service         ip                date            until
PONS1   79.109.1.200    11.10.2014 17:17    11.10.2014 19:17
PONS2   71.109.160.123  11.10.2014 19:09    12.10.2014 3:09
PONS2   71.109.160.123  11.10.2014 23:09    12.10.2014 7:09
PONS2   71.109.160.123  12.10.2014 3:09     12.10.2014 11:09
PONS3   71.109.160.123  12.10.2014 7:09     12.10.2014 15:09
PONS4   71.109.160.123  12.10.2014 16:19    12.10.2014 17:19
PONS4   71.109.160.123  12.10.2014 16:49    13.10.2014 0:49
PONS5   21.110.151.110  13.10.2014 9:22     13.10.2014 11:22
PONS5   21.110.151.110  13.10.2014 10:34    13.10.2014 12:34
PONS5   21.110.151.110  13.10.2014 11:46    13.10.2014 13:46
PONS5   21.110.151.110  13.10.2014 11:46    13.10.2014 13:46
```

I need to modify my query to achieve this: (latest record for every ip address)

```
service         ip                date            until
PONS1   79.109.1.200    11.10.2014 17:17    11.10.2014 19:17
PONS4   71.109.160.123  12.10.2014 16:49    13.10.2014 0:49
PONS5   21.110.151.110  13.10.2014 11:46    13.10.2014 13:46
```

I tried things like sub-query, but my table is too large (~ 1 billion rows) to process it quite quickly. Also I tried to add max(date) with group by ip, but no luck..

Any ideas?

Comment: The dates are reformatted in the presentation layer?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood you correctly, but date column is not reformatted. data is straight form DB.

Comment: Dates in SQL adhere to a specific format. You cannot deviate from it.

Comment: I have timestamp format on Date and Until column.

Comment: So the result snippet presented above isn't 'straight from the database' !?!?

Comment: Oh now I understand.. sorry.
Yes its formatted a bit. And my datatype on Date column is "Datetime"
Original formating: 2014-05-30 11:16:03

Comment: Wish you'd stick with that!  Much less confusing!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `not exists` to select all rows where another row with the same ip and a more recent date does not exist (which means that the selected rows are the most recent for their ip addresses)

```
select d.service,
d.ip,
d.date,
d.until
from dhcp_logs_public d
where d.ip in('79.109.1.200','71.109.160.123','21.110.151.110')
and d.date >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -48 Hour)
and not exists (
    select 1 from dhcp_logs_public d2
    where d2.ip = d.ip
    and d2.date > d.date
)
```

This query can take advantage of a composite index on `(ip,date)`

**Edit**

If you can rely on the `id` column to determine how recent a row is then the following might be faster

```
select d.service,
d.ip,
d.date,
d.until
from dhcp_logs_public d
where d.ip in in('79.109.1.200','71.109.160.123','21.110.151.110')
and d.date >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -48 Hour)
and d.id = (select max(id) from dhcp_logs_public d2 where d2.ip = d.ip)
```

or with a derived table instead of a subquery

```
select d.service,
d.ip,
d.date,
d.until
from dhcp_logs_public d
join (
    select max(id) max_id
    from dhcp_logs_public
    where d.ip in in('79.109.1.200','71.109.160.123','21.110.151.110')
    and d.date >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -48 Hour)
    group by ip 
) t1 on t1.max_id = d.id
```

Comment: actually thats worked, the only question is performance.. query with 3 ip ran ~8 seconds... And I have indexes on my ip and date columns.

Comment: @Viktors do you have 2 separate indexes or a single composite index?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure GROUP BY doesn't work ?

Else try this :

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
    MAX(dhcp_logs_public.service) as service,
    dhcp_logs_public.ip,
    MAX(dhcp_logs_public.date) as date,
    MAX(dhcp_logs_public.until) as until

    FROM dhcp_logs_public
    WHERE dhcp_logs_public.ip in('79.109.1.200','71.109.160.123','21.110.151.110')
    AND dhcp_logs_public.date >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -96 Hour)
    GROUP BY dhcp_logs_public.ip
```

Comment: this will not work since you only group by the IP, but want to display all fields

Comment: When you group by a field, you conserve other fields and I order by in my request for conserve all fields of the last record for each ip. No ?

Comment: no because who should the databasesystem know which service_number, date or until field it should display when you are only grouping by the ip?

Comment: Yes ^^ With this, it's take the last record for each ip

Comment: no, I have tested this earlier. This kind of query gets 3 results, but not the latest ones.

Comment: Are you sure your columns date and until was in datetime type and no in varchar ?

Comment: Ok, you want just service_number, ip, date and until or more fields ? Because for this 4 fields this query works.

Comment: No it isn't working, its returning not the latest record, i have checked this query many times.
Yes I need just those 4 columns.

Comment: Check this fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/045f9/6 I have change the query -48 Hour to adjust at -96 Hour because your data was older. I have also change some parts of query. I have updated this post !